# Performance Problems with JS postMessage to adjust parent iframe scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, event-listener, postmessage

I have a file browser application I want to integrate into an iframe of a main website.
To adjust the scroll height of the iframte to the content I use following code:

iframecontent:

```
    window.top.postMessage({ height: document.body.scrollHeight }, "*");
```

main site html:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://mysubfilebrowser.com"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="10000">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
<script>
    let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");

    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        let message = e.data;

        iframe.style.height = message.height + 'px';
    } , false);
</script>
```

This works as it should but I have problems with performance. If I click in file/folder tree to fast, the post message event seems to be fired so much, that the iframe suddenly do not show the correct content or even empty areas.

Any hints what I can do, to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
Mini25

Comment: How are you calling `postMessage`? That is, what's making the call happen? Some event?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I call it with this line of code:
window.top.postMessage({ height: document.body.scrollHeight }, "*");

The message is posted after each click on a Folder in this File browser because the File/Folder Tree then normaly extends and the scroll hight has to be adjusted.

Comment: That was clear from the question. I meant: what makes that line of code run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a "single" change makes that call run many times (the `scroll` and `resize` events can be like that, amongst others). To handle that, you can "debounce" your call to `postMessage` so it only makes the call once when it gets a lot of triggers in a short period of time.

It's quite simple to do: don't do the call right away, wait up to (say) 10, 50, or 100ms before doing it, and if you get another trigger to do it, reset that delay. That means you won't actually do it until things have settled down.

Here's a simple ad hoc version just for that code, but a web search for "debounce" will turn up various general-purpose debouncing wrappers for functions:

```
let updateWindowDebounceTimer = 0;
function updateWindow() {
    // If there's a pending previous call, cancel it
    clearTimeout(updateWindowDebounceTimer);
    // Schedule a call for 10ms from now
    updateWindowDebounceTimer = setTimeout(sendUpdate, 100);
}
function sendUpdate() {
    updateWindowDebounceTimer = 0;
    window.top.postMessage({ height: document.body.scrollHeight }, "*");
}
```

Then use `updateWindow();` where you're currently using `window.top.postMessage(/*...*/)`.

Here's an example using the `scroll` event **without** debouncing (notice how fast the counter goes up when you scroll):

```js
function updateWindow() {
    /*
    window.top.postMessage({ height: document.body.scrollHeight }, "*");
    */
    const display = document.getElementById("counter");
    display.textContent = String(parseInt(display.textContent, 10) + 1);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", updateWindow);
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#counter {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.tall {
    margin-top: 1em;
    height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">0</div>
<div class="tall">Scroll over this div</div>
```

And here's an example *with* debouncing (notice how much more slowly the counter goes up, indicating fewer update calls):

```js
let updateWindowDebounceTimer = 0;
function updateWindow() {
    // If there's a pending previous call, cancel it
    clearTimeout(updateWindowDebounceTimer);
    // Schedule a call for 10ms from now
    updateWindowDebounceTimer = setTimeout(sendUpdate, 50);
}
function sendUpdate() {
    updateWindowDebounceTimer = 0;
    /*
    window.top.postMessage({ height: document.body.scrollHeight }, "*");
    */
    const display = document.getElementById("counter");
    display.textContent = String(parseInt(display.textContent, 10) + 1);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", updateWindow);
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#counter {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.tall {
    margin-top: 1em;
    height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">0</div>
<div class="tall">Scroll over this div</div>
```

That's an ad-hoc version, but a web search for "debounce" will turn up various general-purpose debouncing wrappers for functions.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. This solution seems to work! Thank you very much!